# Screen Goes Black/Blank After Trying to Run Xubuntu?

Tags: wubi, xubuntu, boot-failure

I just used Wubi to install Xubuntu to my computer. The install seemed successful. I rebooted my computer, and I selected Xubuntu from the options (the two options were Xubuntu and Windows 7, my default OS). However, Xubuntu just sort of flashes some text across the screen then lets me choose from a few "boot modes", I choose the Normal mode, and then I'm taken to a blank screen (black background, flashing white cursor, can't type anything in, nothing happens). And within around a minute of the blank screen, its like my laptop monitor completely shuts down (everything goes black, and the monitor isn't displaying black, but its completely off).

How can I fix this?

By the way, I'm using an HP Pavilion g7 laptop. I'm not entirely sure, but I believe [this](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/HP+-+Pavilion+Laptop+/+Intel%AE+Core%26%23153%3B+i3+Processor+/+17.3%26%2334%3B+Display+/+4GB+Memory+-+Pewter/3441304.p?id=1218402868391&skuId=3441304&st=HP%20Pavilion%20g7&cp=1&lp=1) is the one I purchased.

It comes with Windows 7 by default and I'm trying to use Wubi to install the latest version of Xubuntu.

Comment: Bob hasn't logged on since Oct 31st, day after question asked. Question abandoned?..

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the nomodeset boot option, following the Wubi-specific instructions at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 (method 2 in [post #8](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10089820&postcount=8), assuming you used Wubi to install Xubuntu 11.10).